# Buffer 2 dimensional array, start from 2nd row

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer

I have initialized a buffer array for use:

```
for (h = 0; h < this.height; h += 1) {  this.buffer.push([]);

    for (w = 0; w < this.width; w += 1) {       this.buffer[h][w] = 0;  }
```

For a 2 dimensional list that look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aysS4.png):

I use this buffer for many things and not only that list and I would like to buffer this list, starting from h = 2 (as in the picture, starting to buffer from 2nd row) and ONLY for this list, not for all other things.

The list I want to buffer:

```
this.Stash = new Container("Stash", 15, this.StashY, 10);
```

In this case, the list is 15x10, so the first 2 rows should not be included (which means I would like to buffer over 13x10 area

I am only a beginner and I still have lots of problems with writing a code, but I rewrote it in several ways and all of them still included first 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hStart = 0;

for (h = hStart; h < this.height; h += 1) {  
    for (w = 0; w < this.width; w += 1) {       
        // perform operations 
    }
}
```

I also formatted the code, you generally want to go for readability instead of compactness.

Comment: Hey Will, you comment is much appreciated. Formation of the code, for some reason, I couldn't copy and paste it onto Stackoverflow and that's why it looks so ugly. Second thing, I already did this and like I said, I use this buffer for a few other things which can not start at h = 2, which makes my other scripts not work. It's like I need h = 2 only for this.Stash, and I have a few others, like this.Inventory, this.Cube, etc. and they can not start at h = 2.

Comment: I think I've got it now, I've edited my answer. Just set hStart to whichever row you want to start from.